# Git reflog twice same hash

Tags: git

Can someone explain the following output of reflog:

```
# git reflog
a4a1625 HEAD@{0}: reset: moving to @{1}
7fb9d64 HEAD@{1}: commit: more fixes
a4a1625 HEAD@{2}: commit: few more small css fixes
7fb9d64 HEAD@{3}: commit: more css fixing from global overrides
37578c1 HEAD@{4}: pull: Merge made by the 'recursive' strategy.
7095fba HEAD@{5}: commit: fixing my css that got overwritten by global styles.css
```

Notice HEAD@{1} and HEAD@{3} - why does that happen?? and how can I get back to commit HEAD@{1}??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Git uses SHA1 hashes for object identification. SHA1 hash length is 40 symbols. Command `git reflog` in output uses short version of hashes. Check full version of hashes by commands:

```
git log --grep='more fixes'
git log --grep='more css fixing from global overrides'
```

Most likely you will have different hashes.

To reset branch state to HEAD@{1} use [**git reset**](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-reset.html) command:

```
git reset --hard HEAD@{1}
```

Comment: A simpler way to see the full SHA-1 is to use `git rev-parse`: `git rev-parse HEAD@{1}`, `git rev-parse HEAD@{3}`.

Comment: running git log --grep='more fixes' yields nothing.  Absolutely nothing... not even an error.

on the other hand, git rev-parse HEAD@{1} yields a hash that looks nothing like the hash in reflog, but with a warning before it the states:
warning: Log .git/logs/HEAD has a gap after Thu, 14 Nov 2013 21:05:15 -0500.